# Electron BrowserWindow Facebook Login Failed to Set Cookies

Tags: facebook, cookies, authentication, electron

I am using Facebook Authentication in my Electron desktop app. I am loading the FB auth view into an Electron BrowserWindow. When the BrowserWindow first loads, I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
```

And when I try to login, I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
```

Here is how I am loading my the raw HTML for the Facebook view (data['_body']) into the BrowserWindow:

```
let windowProperties = {
            height: 900,
            width: 1200,
            webPreferences: {
                webSecurity: false,
                nodeIntegration: false
            }
          };
          let win = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow(windowProperties)
          win.loadURL('data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(data["_body"]));
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [browserWindow.webContents.Session](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md). If you are working with older versions of electron you might look at [Electron-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies).